# Can UNAVAIL zfs be recovered?

Tags: vmware-esxi, zfs, ubuntu-18.04, data-recovery

My zfs pool is UNAVAIL and cannot be imported. I wonder if there would be any possibility that it is recovered or I can take out any data from it?

**Background**

I took over management of a server that has a Ubuntu 18.04 VM on VMware ESXi, where the zfs pool is, with two other VMs.

Since the zfs pool was full, I did `zfs add` to add extra 12 TB disc (sdi). (Given that other discs are 4 TB, this asymmetry is probably not ideal, but the disc seemed to be recognized and the VM was running healthy.) I think it was a problem that I set its disk mode to "Independent-persistent", which seems to mean the disc is not restored by snapshot.

Then, since a boot drive of the VM (`sda, lvm, nextcloud-vg`) was full, I tried to expand the lvm to `sdj` by `lvextend`. (I was too naive and stupid to take a snapshot before that.) Then, the VM got unbootable, where Grub did not find the boot disc. I noticed that this was because `sdj` was SCSI(0:10) and not recognized by BIOS at booting.

When I changed the SCSI ID of previous `sdj` to (0:2), Grub found the boot disc, but the VM was still unbootable since the Ubuntu files were somehow massively lost. Then, I restored the files in `sda/nextcloud-vg` by copying from old snapshot. Now, the VM is bootable but cannot read and import the zfs pool.

I really appreciate any comment and suggestion. Thank you so much for reading.

*Healthy zfs pool as of Nov. 2019, which is accessible by a snapshot of VMware.*

```
root@nextcloud:~# zpool status
  pool: ncdata
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 51h42m with 0 errors on Tue Nov 12 04:06:08 2019
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        ncdata      ONLINE       0     0     0
          sdb       ONLINE       0     0     0
          sdc       ONLINE       0     0     0
          sdd       ONLINE       0     0     0
          sde       ONLINE       0     0     0
          sdf       ONLINE       0     0     0
          sdg       ONLINE       0     0     0
          sdh       ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

root@nextcloud:~# zdb
ncdata:
    version: 5000
    name: 'ncdata'
    state: 0
    txg: 6813984
    pool_guid: 4115695041733501295
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'nextcloud'
    com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
    vdev_children: 7
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'root'
        id: 0
        guid: 4115695041733501295
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 0
            guid: 12100899330530807388
            path: '/dev/sdb1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 131
            metaslab_shift: 28
            ashift: 12
            asize: 42934468608
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 129
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 130
        children[1]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 1
            guid: 12620057802260459555
            path: '/dev/sdc1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 256
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1469
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 135
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 136
        children[2]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 2
            guid: 3074381589662896744
            path: '/dev/sdd1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 384
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1472
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 137
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 138
        children[3]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 3
            guid: 1759578235837374106
            path: '/dev/sde1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 140
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1475
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 512
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 513
        children[4]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 4
            guid: 10518026248187884540
            path: '/dev/sdf1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 259
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1478
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 257
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 258
        children[5]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 5
            guid: 8733140335356986716
            path: '/dev/sdg1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 640
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1481
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 386
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 387
        children[6]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 6
            guid: 4551718362642717333
            path: '/dev/sdh1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 369
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1603266
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 349
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 368
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
```

*Current situation.*

```
root@nextcloud:~# zpool import
   pool: ncdata
     id: 4115695041733501295
  state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
 config:

        ncdata      UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
          sdb       ONLINE
          sde       ONLINE
          sdf       ONLINE
          sdg       ONLINE
          sdh       ONLINE
          sdi       ONLINE
          sdj       ONLINE
          sdi       UNAVAIL  corrupted data

root@nextcloud:~# zdb -C
ncdata:
    version: 5000
    name: 'ncdata'
    state: 0
    txg: 6813824
    pool_guid: 4115695041733501295
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'nextcloud'
    com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
    vdev_children: 7
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'root'
        id: 0
        guid: 4115695041733501295
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 0
            guid: 12100899330530807388
            path: '/dev/sdb1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 131
            metaslab_shift: 28
            ashift: 12
            asize: 42934468608
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 129
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 130
        children[1]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 1
            guid: 12620057802260459555
            path: '/dev/sdc1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 256
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1469
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 135
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 136
        children[2]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 2
            guid: 3074381589662896744
            path: '/dev/sdd1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 384
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1472
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 137
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 138
        children[3]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 3
            guid: 1759578235837374106
            path: '/dev/sde1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 140
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1475
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 512
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 513
        children[4]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 4
            guid: 10518026248187884540
            path: '/dev/sdf1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 259
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1478
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 257
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 258
        children[5]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 5
            guid: 8733140335356986716
            path: '/dev/sdg1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 640
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1481
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 386
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 387
        children[6]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 6
            guid: 4551718362642717333
            path: '/dev/sdh1'
            whole_disk: 1
            metaslab_array: 369
            metaslab_shift: 35
            ashift: 12
            asize: 4398031306752
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 1603266
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 349
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 368
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
```

```
root@nextcloud:/dev/disk# zdb -d ncdata
zdb: can't open 'ncdata': Value too large for defined data type
root@nextcloud:/dev/disk# zdb -e -p /dev -d ncdata
zdb: can't open 'ncdata': File exists
root@nextcloud:/mytmpdev# zdb -e -p /dev -AAA -d ncdata
zdb: can't open 'ncdata': File exists

root@nextcloud:/dev/disk# zdb -e ncdata

Configuration for import:
        version: 5000
        pool_guid: 4115695041733501295
        name: 'ncdata'
        state: 0
        vdev_children: 8
        vdev_tree:
            type: 'root'
            id: 0
            guid: 4115695041733501295
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 12100899330530807388
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 131
                metaslab_shift: 28
                ashift: 12
                asize: 42934468608
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1102
                create_txg: 4
                path: '/dev/sdb1'
            children[1]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 1
                guid: 12620057802260459555
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 256
                metaslab_shift: 35
                ashift: 12
                asize: 4398031306752
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1109
                create_txg: 1469
                path: '/dev/sde1'
            children[2]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 2
                guid: 3074381589662896744
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 384
                metaslab_shift: 35
                ashift: 12
                asize: 4398031306752
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1108
                create_txg: 1472
                path: '/dev/sdf1'
            children[3]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 3
                guid: 1759578235837374106
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 140
                metaslab_shift: 35
                ashift: 12
                asize: 4398031306752
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1107
                create_txg: 1475
                path: '/dev/sdg1'
            children[4]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 4
                guid: 10518026248187884540
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 259
                metaslab_shift: 35
                ashift: 12
                asize: 4398031306752
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1103
                create_txg: 1478
                path: '/dev/sdh1'
            children[5]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 5
                guid: 8733140335356986716
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 640
                metaslab_shift: 35
                ashift: 12
                asize: 4398031306752
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1106
                create_txg: 1481
                path: '/dev/sdi1'
            children[6]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 6
                guid: 4551718362642717333
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 369
                metaslab_shift: 35
                ashift: 12
                asize: 4398031306752
                is_log: 0
                DTL: 1105
                create_txg: 1603266
                path: '/dev/sdj1'
            children[7]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 7
                guid: 5107684954562511391
                whole_disk: 1
                metaslab_array: 1058
                metaslab_shift: 36
                ashift: 12
                asize: 13194124328960
                is_log: 0
                create_txg: 6813878
                path: '/dev/sdk1'
        rewind-policy:
            rewind-request-txg: 18446744073709551615
            rewind-request: 2
zdb: can't open 'ncdata': File exists

ZFS_DBGMSG(zdb):
```

```
root@nextcloud:/mytmpdev# zdb -l /dev/sdb1
------------------------------------
LABEL 0
------------------------------------
    version: 5000
    name: 'ncdata'
    state: 0
    txg: 9549126
    pool_guid: 4115695041733501295
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'nextcloud'
    top_guid: 12100899330530807388
    guid: 12100899330530807388
    vdev_children: 8
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'disk'
        id: 0
        guid: 12100899330530807388
        path: '/dev/sdb1'
        whole_disk: 1
        metaslab_array: 131
        metaslab_shift: 28
        ashift: 12
        asize: 42934468608
        is_log: 0
        DTL: 1102
        create_txg: 4
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
    labels = 0 1 2 3
root@nextcloud:/mytmpdev# zdb -l /dev/sdk1
------------------------------------
LABEL 0
------------------------------------
    version: 5000
    name: 'ncdata'
    state: 0
    txg: 6813880
    pool_guid: 4115695041733501295
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'nextcloud'
    top_guid: 5107684954562511391
    guid: 5107684954562511391
    vdev_children: 8
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'disk'
        id: 7
        guid: 5107684954562511391
        path: '/dev/sdi1'
        whole_disk: 1
        metaslab_array: 1058
        metaslab_shift: 36
        ashift: 12
        asize: 13194124328960
        is_log: 0
        create_txg: 6813878
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
    labels = 0 1 2 3
```

```
root@nextcloud:~# lsblk
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                        8:0    0    40G  0 disk
└─sda1                     8:1    0    40G  0 part
  ├─nextcloud--vg-root   253:0    0     1T  0 lvm  /
  └─nextcloud--vg-swap_1 253:1    0   976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                        8:16   0    40G  0 disk
├─sdb1                     8:17   0    40G  0 part
└─sdb9                     8:25   0     8M  0 part
sdc                        8:32   0     4T  0 disk
└─nextcloud--vg-root     253:0    0     1T  0 lvm  /
sdd                        8:48   0     4T  0 disk
├─sdd1                     8:49   0     1M  0 part
├─sdd2                     8:50   0 976.8G  0 part
└─sdd3                     8:51   0 976.8G  0 part
sde                        8:64   0     4T  0 disk
├─sde1                     8:65   0     4T  0 part
└─sde9                     8:73   0     8M  0 part
sdf                        8:80   0     4T  0 disk
├─sdf1                     8:81   0     4T  0 part
└─sdf9                     8:89   0     8M  0 part
sdg                        8:96   0     4T  0 disk
├─sdg1                     8:97   0     4T  0 part
└─sdg9                     8:105  0     8M  0 part
sdh                        8:112  0     4T  0 disk
├─sdh1                     8:113  0     4T  0 part
└─sdh9                     8:121  0     8M  0 part
sdi                        8:128  0     4T  0 disk
├─sdi1                     8:129  0     4T  0 part
└─sdi9                     8:137  0     8M  0 part
sdj                        8:144  0     4T  0 disk
├─sdj1                     8:145  0     4T  0 part
└─sdj9                     8:153  0     8M  0 part
sdk                        8:160  0    12T  0 disk
├─sdk1                     8:161  0    12T  0 part
└─sdk9                     8:169  0     8M  0 part
sr0                       11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

```
root@nextcloud:/dev/disk# parted -l
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 42.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  42.9GB  42.9GB  primary               boot, lvm


Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 42.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  42.9GB  42.9GB  zfs          zfs-7c215dc258f390a2
 9      42.9GB  42.9GB  8389kB


Error: /dev/sdc: unrecognised disk label
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 4398GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 4398GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1049GB  1049GB  ext4
 3      1049GB  2098GB  1049GB  ext4


Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 4398GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  4398GB  4398GB  zfs          zfs-bb77ffc8c56c704c
 9      4398GB  4398GB  8389kB


Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 4398GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  4398GB  4398GB  zfs          zfs-e5f9cec454077158
 9      4398GB  4398GB  8389kB


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/nextcloud--vg-swap_1: 1023MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  1023MB  1023MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/nextcloud--vg-root: 1100GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  1100GB  1100GB  ext4


Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdk: 13.2TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  13.2TB  13.2TB  zfs          zfs-e5495635496c5b84
 9      13.2TB  13.2TB  8389kB


Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdi: 4398GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  4398GB  4398GB  zfs          zfs-b18c76425dec00d4
 9      4398GB  4398GB  8389kB


Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 4398GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  4398GB  4398GB  zfs          zfs-7662c1d580329ece
 9      4398GB  4398GB  8389kB


Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdj: 4398GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  4398GB  4398GB  zfs          zfs-45572a27b3ca3dd5
 9      4398GB  4398GB  8389kB


Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdh: 4398GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  4398GB  4398GB  zfs          zfs-a3d1bd676c04ef35
 9      4398GB  4398GB  8389kB
```

Comment: Please post the *exact command history*

Comment: I don't remember exactly, and operations from GUIs are mixed, but

lvextend -L +1T `/dev/nextcloud-vg
-> reboot (not booted)
-> boot repair form boot-repair-disc
-> sdj was set to SCSI(0:2) on ESXi
-> (from snapshot of Nov. 2019) sudo scp -p -r /bin /boot /etc /lib /lib64 /opt /sbin /usr /var user@anotherVM:/mnt
-> (on the unbootable VM booted by iso image) sudo mount /dev/nextcoloud-vg/root /mnt
-> (on the unbootable VM booted by iso image) scp -p -r user@anotehrVM:/bin /mnt
(repeated for  /boot /etc /lib /lib64 /opt /sbin /usr /var )

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the link from your failed zfs import: https://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E/, at the bottom

> If this error is encountered during 'zpool import', the action is the same [as below] The pool cannot be imported - all data is lost and must be restored from an appropriate backup source.

A bit above it says

> ZFS will be unable to use the pool, and all data within the pool is irrevocably lost. The pool must be destroyed and recreated from an appropriate backup source.

If you have a snapshot of the data, then you could recreate the ZFS pool, and then manually copy over the files from the snapshot to new pool.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It's probably most practical to once go back to the last snapshot.

I saw however some recovery cases even from "ZFS-8000-5E". So just wondered if it might also the case for mine.
https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/zfs-zpool-unavailable.5936/
https://navyfox.hatenadiary.org/entries/2009/11/29